# Urls indexed in Google with index.php Laravel 9

Tags: laravel

I'm facing a problem with google's WebMasterConsole, some posts are indexed as follows url.com/index.php/posts/57 when the person enters, the site doesn't change anything but the adsense ads are not displayed, someone passed so is it google search problem or is it some htaccess rule? laravel 9 project.

I tried several solutions here from stackoverflow but none solved it on localhost so that I can implement it in production, does anyone have any idea what I might be doing to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

My .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: share the code routes and layout of the post page.

Comment: @JSTECH Hi, thanks for your comment. There is no need to post the page view and route, as it is displayed normally and there is no redirection with prefix /index.php because other post pages are correctly indexed by google, everything I found here on stackoverflow is related to htaccess, however any change to htaccess doesn't change anything even clearing cache: clear, view:clear: config:clear. Thanks in advance. I hope I have clarified the above question more.